# How to loop from different type of Arraylist values and display on listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have the code here:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        ArrayList values = new ArrayList();    

        public Form1()
        {
           values.Add(10);
           values.Add(40);
           values.AddRange(new int[] { 90, 30, 19, 59 });
           values.Insert(0, 100);
           values.Add("Hello Collection");
           values.Add(new Person("Tola", 20, "Phnom Penh"));
           InitializeComponent();
        }
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
              ViewList();       
       }

       public void ViewList()
       { 
          foreach (int i in values)
            listShow.Items.Add(i);
       }
   }
```

I don't know how to display them in a listbox. I want to create loop for displaying values in a Listbox as you see in function named `ViewList()`. I can try only one datatype of arraylist. But if I have ultiple different datatypes in ArrayList, Is it possible for looping different arraylist with their own datatpes? Thanks.

Comment: Which is it - JavaScript, Java or C#? The code looks like C# and since I'm not familiar with C# I can only guess: there might be a type `Object` as in Java and thus you could use that in the loop and either add it directly to `Items` or create a string represenation of it and add the string.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell what kind of codes. It's C# language. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you remove the excess tags then.

Comment: Could you give an example, please?

Comment: As I said I don't know C# that well but in Java I'd do something like `for( Object o : values) { listShow.items.add( o.toString() ); }` - it depends on what type of item you need though so it might or might not be what you want. However, it should get you started and with some reading the documentation it should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the arraylist to the listview?

```
lbMyListBox.Datasource = values;
lbMyListBox.Databind();
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much. And how about deletion, could you give me some guideline, please?

Comment: deleting a specific value from the listbox?

Comment: Yes, sir. Please help me.

Comment: you would need to post a new question please

Comment: thanks. sorry, I am a new one here just 10 mins ago.